# (Visual Studio): "Find All References"- Hide Unconfirmed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, find

When you right-click on any symbol and select "Find All References" (or just press Shift-F12) VS2015 shows ALL occurrences where symbol with the same name appears.

This is very inconvenient, because, for example, I can have a lot of methods with the same name in different classes, but I want to see references only for one of them.

It is almost like a find-word search... Thankfully, VS not show all comments and string constants with the same word...

According to links below there was an option to "Hide Unconfirmed" references in previous versions of the VS, but now this option is gone:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794540/hide-unconfirmed-has-gone-missing-from-find-symbol-results

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2009/11/17/improvements-to-find-all-references-in-visual-studio-2010/

How can I find only "real" references of the symbol?
Is there some solution for this problem, maybe certain VS extension, or something?

I just can't believe that there is a lack of basic functionality in VS.
How guys from Microsoft is even work themselves?...

Comment: Seems they (re)introduced this functionality only with VS 2017 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/find-all-references-re-designed-for-larger-searches/